# I am having shopping cart icon and i have (0) count in bracket

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am having shopping cart icon on home page which displays cart count.Now i want to check if cart count is 0 then print cart is empty else print list of items.The value of cart count which i am getting is in format like (0) in brackets.

Selenium with java using POM

```
  System.out.println("Cart count is:-" +Cartcount.getText());
        /*String s1="(0)";  
        String replaceString=s1.replace('(',' ');
        String replaceString1=s1.replace(')',' ');
        //replaces all occurrences of 'a' to 'e'  
        System.out.println(replaceString);  
        System.out.println(replaceString1);  */
         String str = "(0)";  
            System.out.println("Split");  
            String[] arr = str.split("(0)",2);  
            for (String w : arr) {  
                System.out.println(w);  
            }  
         //   System.out.println("Split array length: "+arr.length);
    /*  String Cartcount=driver.findElement(By.id("cart_item_count")).getText();
        System.out.println(Cartcount);
        String tem[]=Cartcount.split(" ");
        System.out.println(tem[2]);
        String temp[]=tem[2].split("\\(");
        System.out.println(temp[1]);*/

        if (Cartcount.equals(0)) {
            System.out.println("Cart is empty") ;   
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.printf("Cart is not empty");
        }
Output-
Cart count is:-(0)
Split
(
)
Cart is not empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "Cartcount.equals(0)" you can use "Cartcount.contains(0)".

It will resolve your problem and no need for extra logics.